# Checking the lengths of all my arrays in Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, for-loop

My goal is to have a bunch of arrays, para1, para2.... para20, and find all of the arrays with multiple elements in it, and then to be able to access them. For example I want an if statement in a for loop that would basically check all of my arrays to see which ones have multiple elements. Then, for the ones that do have multiple elements I would use an if statement to extract a particular item from each array.

```
var para1 = ["NB4-CAXL-14U-12-"];
var para2 = ["K"];
var para3 = ["-270°C to 1372°C, –454°F to 2501°F"];
var para4 = ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"'];
var para5 = ['6"', '12"', '18"'];

for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
    var lenId = "para" + j;
    console.log(lenId.length);
}

document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = typeof lenId;
```

I defined a few arrays and made a for loop that generated a variable that was the name of each of the arrays, but when i went to check the length of the arrays i realized they are all 5, because `lenId = "para1"` is just a string with 5 letters in it. How would i be able to check `para1` to see how many elements are in the array? Or is there a better method for checking the length of all my arrays by possibly putting them all into one larger array or something? Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: use multi dimension arrays... basically an array of arrays

Comment: @Liquidchrome - An array of arrays, is not a multidimensional array.  Two different things.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/597720/what-are-the-differences-between-a-multidimensional-array-and-an-array-of-arrays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the arrays in an object:

```js
//Initializing the object:
var O = {
  para1: ["NB4-CAXL-14U-12-"],
  para2: ["K"],
  para3: ["-270°C to 1372°C, –454°F to 2501°F"],
  para4: ['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"']
};

//Adding a new key to the object:
O.para5 = ['6"', '12"', '18"'];

//Getting the object's keys and their lengths:
for(var j in O) {
  console.log(j + ': ' + O[j].length);
}

//Accessing an individual array element:
console.log(O.para4[1]);   //3/16"

//Iterating through the object's array values using a for loop
for(var j in O) {
  for(var i = 0 ; i < O[j].length ; i++) {
    console.log(j + ': Element ' + i + ': Value ' + O[j][i]);
  }
}

//Iterating through the object's array values using forEach
for(var j in O) {
  O[j].forEach(function(val, i) {
    console.log(j + ': Element ' + i + ': Value ' + val);
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked perfectly. But what does it mean if in the console it says: VM39 extensions::schemaUtils:112Uncaught Error: Invocation of form runtime.connect(null, ) doesn't match definition runtime.connect(optional string extensionId, optional object connectInfo)? The only other thing in my code is a for loop that i've had for a long time and haven't changed so I don't know what could be causing it..

Comment: Sorry, that's new to me.  Are you running this in an extension?

Comment: I'm using Jsfiddle

Comment: That's strange.  I don't see the same effect in JSFiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/s8m84c0u/  What browser are you using?

Comment: @ Rick Hitchcock - I'm using Chrome, and it's weird cause I have this code open on 2 different computers right now and 1 of them has the error and the other one doesn't so it must not be code related... I suppose it's not important since everything seems to be working correctly with the code. Thanks for the help

Comment: @ Rick Hitchcock - I just realized, your code works for accessing each of the sub arrays themselves, but how would i access an element inside a sub array? for example when i use O[3] i get ["1/8"", "3/16"", "1/4""] as the output, but how do i get 3/16"? Its like I want to take O[3][1]

Comment: Instead of `O[3][1]`, you would use `O.para4[1]` or `O['para4'][1]`.  Objects provide a lot of power and flexibility, and they can *somewhat* emulate an associative array.  I've provided more examples in my code for working with the object.

Comment: @ Rick Hitchcock, thanks again you're a life saver! My problem was that in my loop i was going from j = 0 to the length of O so my j was a number which is why i couldn't do O[j][i], whereas your j is the actual array itself

Answer (score 0):

I would go ahead and throw your arrays into a single array. Then you can more easily do operations over that array without having to worry about numbering. The number is implicit based on the index!

```js
var paras = [];
paras.push(["NB4-CAXL-14U-12-"]);
paras.push(["K"]);
paras.push(["-270°C to 1372°C, –454°F to 2501°F"]);
paras.push(['1/8"', '3/16"', '1/4"']);
paras.push(['6"', '12"', '18"']);

paras.forEach(function(para) {
    console.log(para.length);  
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It's not pretty, but it looks like you are storing these arrays in the global scope (client-side), so technically you could refer to each variable as a property of `window`:

```
for (var j = 1; j < 10; j++) {
 var lenId = "para" + j;
 console.log(window[lenId].length);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If arrays are not dynamically generated and you define them like in your example, the better way to do that is by using standard array method `filter`. It accepts the function as a parameter that returns a `boolean` and tells whether the array item should be filtered or not. You want to use it like so:

```
var para1 = ['1', '2', '3'];
var para2 = ['1'];
var para3 = ['1', '2'];

var arraysToFilter = [para1, para2, para3];

var filteredArray = arraysToFilter.filter(function (paraArray) {

    // returns true if array has more than one element;
    return paraArray.length > 1;
});
```

Now `filteredArray` would be an array with two elements - `para1` and `para3`